# css grid element placement chrome vs. firefox

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I don't know if this is a problem with my code, or a problem with chrome's implementation of the grid spec (or maybe firefox's), but I am seeing elements be misplaced within their grid if I specify a relative position adjustment.

Looking at the following:

**HTML**

```
<div class="sheet-container">
  <div class="sheet-header-block sheet-one"></div>
  <div class="sheet-bottom-left sheet-corner sheet-one"></div>
  <div class="sheet-top-right sheet-corner sheet-one"></div>
  <div class="sheet-header-block sheet-two"></div>
  <div class="sheet-bottom-left sheet-corner sheet-two"></div>
  <div class="sheet-top-right sheet-corner sheet-two"></div>
  <div class="sheet-header-block sheet-three"></div>
  <div class="sheet-bottom-left sheet-corner sheet-three"></div>
  <div class="sheet-top-right sheet-corner sheet-three"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.sheet-container{
    display:grid;
    grid-template-columns: 80px 80px 80px;
    grid-template-rows:40px;
    grid-gap:5px;
    grid-template-areas:"one two three";
    background-color:white;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
.sheet-header-block{
  background-color:red;
}
.sheet-one{
  grid-area:one;
}
.sheet-two{
  grid-area:two;
}
.sheet-three{
  grid-area:three;
}
.sheet-corner{
    position:relative;
    transform:rotate(45deg);
    height:2px;
    width:5px;
    background-color:black;
}
.sheet-bottom-left{
    align-self:end;
    top:-2px;
}
.sheet-top-right{
    justify-self:end;
    left:-4px;
}
```

In firefox, this code results in the corner divs being positioned at their respective corners of the header blocks, but repositioned upward by 2px and and left 4px respectively.

In chrome, having any position adjustment negates the justify-self or align-self properties and puts them in the top-left corner of the header-block. Does anyone have a suggested fix for this?

EDIT: I only need to support the latest couple releases of chrome and firefox. Additional compatibility is of course a plus. Due to the development environment, only classes can be used.

EDT2: [Fiddle](http://fiddlesalad.com/css/relative-positioning-in-a-grid-chrome-vs-firefox) of the issue. The fiddle uses Warren Wan's suggested solution, although it still does not fix the issue in chrome 64.0.3282.167 (Official Build) (64-bit).

Comment: I'm not sure what's supposed to happen but you should not see grid areas the same as elements. The easiest (and logical imho) way to position those corners is to put them inside the `.sheet-header-block` elements and position them from there.

Comment: Yes, grid areas are not the same as elements like divs, according to the spec, positioning a grid element (relatively or absolutely) within a grid area should position it with respect to the grid area (as if the area was a relatively positioned element).

As for why I'm doing it this way, it's actually easier (at least when it works) to position them this way than doing it within the header-block elements because there is less calculation that needs to be done.

Answer (score 1):

You write wrong `css`. `.sheet-top-right` `CSS` should be `left: 0;top: 2px;`. Because of your understanding with `justify-self: end;` then means content will show automatic in right edge. If you set `rotate: 45(deg)` you need to set `top` or `bottom` `position`.

[FireFox test result with FireFox version](http://prntscr.com/ig31t7).

[Chrome test result](http://prntscr.com/ig32j5) and [Chrome version 63.0.3239.132 (Official Build) (64-bit)](http://prntscr.com/ig34bp)

> Note: you should write `css prefix` for support older `browser`.

```
.sheet-top-right{
    justify-self:end;
    left: 0;
    top: 2px;
}
```

```css
.sheet-container{
    display:grid;
    grid-template-columns: 80px 80px 80px;
    grid-template-rows:40px;
    grid-gap:5px;
    grid-template-areas:"one two three";
    background-color:white;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
.sheet-header-block{
  background-color:red;
}
.sheet-one{
  grid-area:one;
}
.sheet-two{
  grid-area:two;
}
.sheet-three{
  grid-area:three;
}
.sheet-corner{
    position:relative;
    transform:rotate(45deg);
    height:2px;
    width:5px;
    background-color:black;
}
.sheet-bottom-left{
    align-self:end;
    top:-2px;
}
.sheet-top-right{
    justify-self:end;
    left: 0;
    top: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="sheet-container">
  <div class="sheet-header-block sheet-one"></div>
  <div class="sheet-bottom-left sheet-corner sheet-one"></div>
  <div class="sheet-top-right sheet-corner sheet-one"></div>
  <div class="sheet-header-block sheet-two"></div>
  <div class="sheet-bottom-left sheet-corner sheet-two"></div>
  <div class="sheet-top-right sheet-corner sheet-two"></div>
  <div class="sheet-header-block sheet-three"></div>
  <div class="sheet-bottom-left sheet-corner sheet-three"></div>
  <div class="sheet-top-right sheet-corner sheet-three"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hmm, interesting, so it's something in the latest chrome release that causes it (64.0.3282.167 (Official Build) (64-bit)) That is good to know. However your suggestion does not solve the problem. I only manipulated a single direction in each one for the sake of a simple example of the problem, however in the actual project, the corner divs are positioned relative both vertically and horizontally.

Answer (score 0):

Its due to CSS cross browser compatibility, do this and you should be fine:

```
.sheet-bottom-left{
    -webkit-align-self:end;
    -moz-align-self:end;
    align-self:end;
    top:-2px;
}

.sheet-top-right{
    -webkit-justify-self:end;
    -moz-justify-self:end;
    justify-self:end;
    left:-4px;
}
```

Note: you might also need to add the -moz- and -webkit- flag to "transform" also.

Comment: This also does not appear to resolve the issue. I've updated the OP with a fiddle that displays the issue.